# how to convert 0x8080 to 8080 int?

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation

how I do this?

`int a = 0x8080;`

it is possible convert it to

`int b = MagicMethod(a); //output:8080`

Comment: Don't you mean `0x8080`?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you have a string containing "0x8080" and you want to convert it to an integer of value 0x8080?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish? What is the relation between 0x808080 and 8080?

Comment: Your question is meaningless.  Please provide more context.  (or datatypes)

Comment: bit manipulation or string manipulation?

Comment: @SLaks: Actually,I received something like 0x808800 that I need convert to  #808080 for use in form backColor.

Comment: You want to be able to do this for any HEX number or just for this concrete number?

Comment: @Jack : in which format you receiving colour code? Anyway `#.....` this is a HEX code so you just need to convert to string and replace `0x` by `#`

Comment: After the Edit: Still meaningless. Add more samples, what should 0xA0A0 become?

Comment: Now is not meaningless but wrong. That's NOT what you want to do.

Comment: why - 3 downvote. it is a real question. :(

Comment: Jack, if you would do what your code does, you would be changing the value of the integer. 0x8080 is base 16. In base 10 that would be 32896, which is not the same as 8080 in base 10. You probably need to read about bases, especially base 10 and 16. 0x8080 = 32896.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: as int. SLaks and Fischermaen solved my problem. thank you too :)

Comment: @Jack: I've edited my answer. There is a MagicConvert function for you ...

Comment: `int b = MagicMethod(a)` And yet you accepted an answer that produces a `string` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a number to hex like this:  `0x8080.ToString("x6")`
The `6` is the number of decimal places.

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) for more detail.

Comment: Exactly it. Thanks very much!

Comment: Next time, please **specify precisely** what you want.  Had you asked how to convert an `int` to a hex string, you would have gotten this answer instantly (probably five of them)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** Accorrding to your edit I must say **Impossible**. You try to convert a hex value in a corresponding int value. This will only work for hex values not containing the hex digits "A" to "F". If you are limited to that, you can do

```
private int MagicConvert(int value)
{
    string intValue = value.ToString("X");
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= intValue.Length; i++)
    {
        int digit;
        if (!int.TryParse(intValue.Substring(intValue.Length - i, 1), out digit))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Hex value contains digits in the range of 'A' to 'F'.");
        }
        result += (int)Math.Pow(10, i - 1) * digit;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string "0x8080" and want to convert it to the integer 0x8080, then you can do this:

```
string s = "0x8080";
uint x = uint.Parse(s.Substring(2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```

**UPDATE**  He wrote above "Actually,I received something like 0x808800 that I need convert to #808080 for use in form backColor." This means to me that he needs to convert the integer 0x80808000 to a Color, which can be done using `Color.FromArgb` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zys7833.aspx)).

Comment: Was about to post this. I think he needs and integer back. Hard to tell for sure though.